# How can I get the images that I upload in my server side?

Tags: reactjs, express, frontend, backend, multer

My problem is that I don't know how to get my images that I input my backend and database...So basically this is my code...

In this middleware part of upload.js

```
const path = require('path')
const multer = require('multer')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req,file,cb) {
        cb(null,'uploads/')
    },
    filename: function(req,file,cb) {
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
        cb(null,Date.now() + ext)
    }
})

var upload = multer({
    storage:storage,
    fileFilter:function(req,file,callback){
        if (
            file.mimetype == "image/png" || file.mimetype == 'image/jpg'
        ) {
            callback(null,true)          
        } else {
            console.log(' Only jpg & png file supported')
            callback(null,false)
        }
    },
    limits: {
        fileSize:1024 * 1024 * 2
    }
})

module.exports = upload
```

I will pass it here at my server/routes/starter.js

```
router.route('/add').post(upload.single('avatar'),(req,res,next) => {

    const fullname = req.body.fullname
    const nickname = req.body.nickname
    const age = req.body.age
    const height = req.body.height
    const weight = req.body.weight
    const date_birth = req.body.date_birth

    const newStarterDeclaration = new Starter({
        fullname,nickname,age,height,weight,date_birth
        // email,phonenumber
    })

    if (req.file) {
        newStarterDeclaration.avatar = req.file.path
    }

    newStarterDeclaration.save()
        .then(starter => res.json('New Record Added!'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error :' + err))

})
```

When I upload this it will be save at my upload folder
I have two main folder.. the client folder and server folder..so basically what I am saying this is how i am gonna get my images at the server folder..I did something like this in my code but it doesn't work..

This is in the folder of client for the List.jsx

```
const Starter = props => (
    <tr>
        <td>{props.starter.fullname}</td>
        <td>{props.starter.nickname}</td>
        <td>{props.starter.age}</td>
        <td>{props.starter.height}</td>
        <td>{props.starter.weight}</td>
        <td><img src={`../server/uploads/${props.starter.avatar.substring(8)}`} alt=""/> {'../server/uploads/'+ props.starter.avatar.substring(8)}</td>
        <td>{new Date(Date.parse(props.starter.date_birth)).toDateString()}</td>
        <td>
            <Link to={'/edit/'+props.starter._id}> Edit</Link>
            <a href="#" onClick={e =>{props.deleteStarter(props.starter._id)}}> Delete </a>
        </td>
    

    </tr>
)
```

Don't mind too much about the others.. just think about this code

```
<td><img src={`../server/uploads/${props.starter.avatar.substring(8)}`} alt=""/> {'../server/uploads/'+ props.starter.avatar.substring(8)}</td>
```

And what I am receiving in the frontend is something like this...

```
Full Name   Nickname    Age Height  Weight  Date Birth  Image   Actions
Xenonon Michael1231 22  1212    121  ../server/uploads/1646981611556.png    Thu Sep 09 2021 Edit Delete
Xenonon Michael2123122  22  1212    121  ../server/uploads/1646981644622.png    Thu Sep 09 2021 Edit Delete
```

As you I try it to show it in the textContent..but when I try it in image it doesn't work.. Am i missing something here???

Can anyone help please haha thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your image paths are relative: `../server/..`. Please have a look (coming from the location of your `.html`-file), if the images are really located there.

You should also have a look into the browser-inspector, which will show you the path, where it is looking for the images.

The best approach is by using full paths (e.g `https://my-server.com/uploads/image1.png`)

Comment: nah already tried this one but ain't work